# Was there a similar chapter to Uncharted 3: "The Chateau" in any of the previous Uncharted games?

Tags: uncharted-series

Maybe I am expiercing a type of deja-vu but I believe the chapter "The Chateau" was played in one of the previous chapters from either Uncharted 1 or 2.

Things I noted were familiar:

- Outside on the path the rusted car that Drake makes a joke to sully "hey look sully its your first car"
- The Chandeliers in the chateau, jumping from side to side in the Chateau from the Chandeliers (this could have happened any previous game chapters though)
- moving the log from blocking the door
- the popcorn machine outside the door.
- The entire Chateau room, shooting the lock off the window and the broken stair case.

Can anyone confirm I'm not crazy and making this all up in my head? or have I just picked random associations from previous chapters in the Uncharted titles that seemed familiar

Comment: That area was used in the demos.. You might simply be remembering em from the promo videos and demos and such that came out while they were making the game.

Comment: @James - nope that's not it, I never played any demos or checked out any promotional videos before release.

Comment: @Jared I played all 3 games in the course of about a month, and I didn't experience the sense of Déjà vu that you did, nor does reading your question invoke in me a particular sense of familiarity with scenes in the first two games. It's possible no one has been able to confirm you're not crazy because you are indeed crazy! :)

Comment: I'm not crazy I tell you!! ;p I think I may need to answer this one myself. Will be back with an answer after done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am way way wayyy late to answer this but dude...the chandelier part was not a deja vu...remember uncharted 1??? you goto the church, jump through the chandeliers to reach the treasure vault?? :) i guess you are remembering that level..